# TWAIN API inside AIR application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, twain

I would like to see support for image acquisition devices in Air. 
I like scan the TWAIN API and view picture inside Air application.

On Web I see some module with Java, but in my case I can't install java on server.

Do you know how to do use Twain api and AIR?

Thanks

Comment: I will nudge you this way: http://www.kasperkamperman.com/blog/flash-code/as3-apply-bitmap-filters-to-a-webcam-image/

Comment: possible duplicate of [TWAIN scanning via AIR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410846/twain-scanning-via-air)